# Groupe each five line in one line - Regex NotePad++

Tags: regex

I have a file text with a large data like this :

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
```

I want group each 5 line into one line like this:

```
ABCDE
FGHIJ
```

I try with this Regex, but it not working

```
Find What: (\r\n{3})
Replace with: $1\n
```

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: doing this task with a better editor or other tools would be much easier than notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*)\R(.*)(?:\R(.*))?(?:\R(.*))?(?:\R(.*))?
```

To replace with `$1$2$3$4$5`. The `\R` stands for any linebreak style, CRLF, CR, or LF. The `^` is necessary (start of line) to make sure we start counting lines from the next after a successful match.

Also note that we need to have at least 1 linebreak to start "merging" lines (see `(.*)\R(.*)` in the beginning of the pattern).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `(.*)\R` - a line with a linebreak at the end, the contents of which are captured into Group 1
- `(.*)` - (Group 2) line after the first one captured
- `(?:\R(.*))?` - optional (1 or 0) linebreak followed with some (0 or more) characters other than a newline  (Group 3)
- `(?:\R(.*))?` - ibid.  (Group 4)
- `(?:\R(.*))?` - ibid. (Group 5)

See the screen below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would do this [like so](https://regex101.com/r/sI9mZ9/2):

```
(?:(.*)\r\n)(?:(.*)\r\n)?(?:(.*)\r\n)?(?:(.*)\r\n)?(?:(.*)\r\n)?
```

And replace with: `$1$2$3$4$5\n`

Comment: I tested with 25 line of data and I got this result

Comment: @Fox Which result ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using notepad++, and if using regex is not an absolute requirement you could also use a simple macro like this:

- place the cursor to first row + first column.
- start recording a macro (Macro -> Start Recording)
- hit "End" / "Del" four times
- hit "Pos1"
- hit "Down arrow"
- stop recording the macro (Macro -> Stop Recording)
- eventually save this macro, if needed another time (Macro -> Save Currently Recorded Macro)

Now play this macro multiple times until end of file (Macro -> Run A Macro Multiple Times)